# How do I define multiple class member in a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, class, input, member

I have a problem for an experiment I am running, where I need to create 40 class members (research mice that have certain properties, such as animal ID, cage ID, color preference, light preference) and then do some manipulations with them. All of these properties are obtained through user input (such as mouse 37B, cage 37, black, bright). A good solution for this could be creating an array and iterating a for loop for each subsequent element and defining it as a class member. I tried this as below, but it didn't work, so I don't know if it's even possible. The actual problem, in short, is how do I create several custom-named members of a class by not explicitly writing a name for them?

```
        var mice = [];

        class Mouse
        {
          constructor(id, cage, color, light) 
          {
            this.id = id;
            this.cage = cage;
            this.color = color;
            this.light = light;
          }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) 
        {
           mice[i] = new Mouse(user_input1, user_input2, user_input3, user_input4);
        }
```

Comment: And how did it not work? What happened when you ran this code? How are you getting the user input?

Comment: This code does exactly what you say you want it to do.  So what's the problem? Haha.

Comment: Please elaborate on "it didn't work".

Comment: I use alert(mice[i].id); which generates a popup declaring "undefined". I know user input is solid because when I call out alert(user_input1); it returns the value I want. Is assigning an array element as a class member even allowed?

Comment: @emama Please provide a [mcve]. The code you provided [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/u2p143wr/).

Comment: How do you get these `user_inputN` values? Do you have some HTML `<input...>` fields? Do you have 40 _sets_ of those? Does this code run when you _Submit_ a form?

Answer (score 0):

I edit youre code by replace input on constarctor with value from loop
and then add input to Enter mouse id and edit it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="mouse_id" type="text" placeholder="mouse_number_id" value=""></input>
<button onclick="edit_lab_mouse()">edit</bytton>
<script>

  var mice = [];

        class Mouse
        {
          constructor(id, cage, color, light) 
          {
            this.id = id;
            this.cage = cage;
            this.color = color;
            this.light = light;
          }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) 
        {
           mice[i] = new Mouse(i, i, i, i);
        }
     
          
        function edit_lab_mouse(){
        var mouse_id=document.getElementById("mouse_id").value;
         mice[mouse_id].color = prompt("Please enter mouse color");
        mice[mouse_id].cage = prompt("Please enter mouse cage");
          mice[mouse_id].light= prompt("Please enter light value");
         mice[mouse_id].id = prompt("Please enter new mouse id");
         
       alert("updated value done");
        }
       

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

While trying to create a minimal reproducible example, my code started to work. The original was rather complicated with trying to feed the input from an excel file through add-on js library (which actually worked as I tested it), so a few things could have gone wrong. I found a few declarations that were incorrect and it all seems to work now; I am able to **assign an array element as a class member**, which is what I was after; looping through this should be easy now. Thank you all for help and sorry for a sloppy first posting; I am very new to this.

Here is my minimal reproducible example that **works**.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>CPP randomizer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Animal ID: <input id="ID"><br>
    Cage number: <input type="number" id="cage"><br>
    Color: <input id="color"><br>
    Light preference: <input id="light"><br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

 
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var mice = [];
            
    class Mouse
    {
      constructor(id, cage, color, light) 
      {
        this.id = id;
        this.cage = cage;
        this.color = color;
        this.light = light;
      }
    }

    function myFunction()
      {
        var id = document.getElementById("ID").value;
        var cage = document.getElementById("cage").value;
        var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
        var light = document.getElementById("light").value;
        mice[0] = new Mouse(id, cage, color, light);
      alert(mice[0].id);
      alert(mice[0].cage);
      alert(mice[0].color);
      alert(mice[0].light);
      }

  </script>
  
</body>
```